# PHP Action Verification

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a site that is very heavily relying on Ajax. To stop major spamming on my site, I decided to implement a PHP system that checks how many actions have been made in the last 5 minutes. I wrote this fairly quickly and I was wondering if there are any major issues with my code. Read the footnote as to why I can't test this. If you see any major errors here, please let me know. Also, spelling errors would be the fault of auto-correct.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once(".conf.php");
    //Main config
    $verification = $_GET['verification_token'];
    $requestactions = $_GET['request_actions'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    //Set up config
    $maxactions = 40;
    $maxactionserror = 'Hmm, it seems you exceded the max actions allowed here. Try again in a few, Thank you!';
    $actiontable = 'actions'
    $currentactions = 0;
    $timeout = 1;
    $cookieexpire = 600 //Time in MS
    $blockreason = 'exceeded action requests';
    //Query config
    $firstquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$actiontable' WHERE username = '$username'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($firstquery);

    function check() {  
        if ($rows) {
            if ($rows >= $maxactions) {
                setcookie['reasonblocked', $blockreason, time() + $cookieexpire);
                setcookie['ipblocked', $ip, time() + $cookieexpire);
                setcookie['blockfinished', 'timestamp', time() + $cookieexpire);       
                $blockquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$actiontable'('eligible') VALUES ('0') WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
                echo $maxactionserror;
                unset($login);
                unset($username);
                session_destroy();
            } else {
                while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($firstquery)) {
                    $currentactions = $get['cactions'];
                    $newactions = $currentactions++;
                    $secondquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$actiontable'('username', 'auth_token', 'cactions', 'userip') VALUES ('$username', '$verification', '$newactions', '$ip')");
                    echo 'success';
                    check();
                }   
            }
        } else {
            $secondquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$actiontable'('username', 'auth_token', 'cactions') VALUES ('$username', '$verification', '1')");
            echo 'success';
        }   
    }
?>
```

---

PS. I am on vacation so I am unable to test this. That is why I posted on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the first thing here: prevent yourself from SQL injections. Of course you can escape your parameters but parametrized queries with PDO or so would be much better. You can also use mysqli - [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php)'s an example:

Also this won't execute since you have syntax errors in there (ie a missing `;` here:  `$cookieexpire = 600 //Time in MS`).

Also, don't rely on cookies for this. If someone really wants to spam, it is really easy just to delete your cookies or just return them in a valid state... store the ipaddress (or ipaddr and the browser-string) and then save that in a database (or something like redis).

There is much more to talk about here, but this would be a good start.

Comment: Ok thanks. I noticed those few errors specifically the `missing ;` after I posted and I never fixed here. I **am** inserting the ip into a database. I don't know why I didn't post that here. Hmm. What else is wrong here?